# Не компилируются Android проекты после обновления Ubuntu с 11.10 до 12.04

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

Добрый день! Суть проблемы в том, что после того, как я обновил linux, у меня при запуске эмулятора начало выводить такое сообщение:

> `[2012-08-18 19:21:29 - ApiDemos] Android Launch!
> [2012-08-18 19:21:29 - ApiDemos] adb is running normally.
> [2012-08-18 19:21:29 - ApiDemos] Performing com.example.android.apis.ApiDemos activity launch
> [2012-08-18 19:21:29 - ApiDemos] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Em41'
> [2012-08-18 19:21:29 - ApiDemos] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Em41'
> [2012-08-18 19:21:41 - Emulator] X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
> [2012-08-18 19:21:41 - Emulator]   Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
> [2012-08-18 19:21:41 - Emulator]   Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
> [2012-08-18 19:21:41 - Emulator]   Serial number of failed request:  12
> [2012-08-18 19:21:41 - Emulator]   Current serial number in output stream:  12`

Уже два дня в инете лазаю, что-то с дровами под видяху шаманю... ничего не помогает.
Кто может сталкивался или подскажет, в каком направлении двигаться?

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, но вы не пробовали Eclipse переустановить (или в чем вы пишите)?

Comment: Думаю, вряд ли проблема с видяхой или дровами - скорее всего, с конфигами.

Comment: @Kernis_Sataier Возможно, поможет - http://askubuntu.com/questions/81344/how-to-fix-error-with-ati-driver-error-of-failed-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо!
Я Linux Mint 13 "Maya" поставил и установил последний Eclipse - всё заработало как часы :-)